# update trigger using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables:

Sales_Order

```
Order_ID       Buyer_ID     Emp_ID     Status (ENUM)
   1              2           3          P
```

Sales_Order_Details

```
Detail_ID      Order_ID     Quantity    Item_ID     Balance
   1              1            10          3           10
   2              1            20          6            5
```

I am trying to create a trigger which looks for updates on the Sales_Order_Details Table and sees that if Balance of any Detail_ID changes, it looks for all the Balance with the Same Order_ID, and if all all 0 then change the status of that Order in Sales_Order table to 'C'.

I am new to triggers and have been reading a few things, but i am quite confused in using them.

```
CREATE TRIGGER flag_order_complete AFTER UPDATE ON Sales_Order_Details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF Balance = '0' THEN
UPDATE Sales_Order SET Status 'C' where Order_ID = old.Order_ID
END
```

Now this probably is horribly wrong. It will be great  if anyone could help me through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are some obvious syntactical issues. You might try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER flag_order_complete AFTER UPDATE ON Sales_Order_Details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE total_balance INT(10);

  SELECT SUM(Balance) INTO total_balance
    FROM Sales_Order_Details
   WHERE Order_ID = new.Order_ID;

  IF (total_balance = 0) THEN
    UPDATE Sales_Order SET Status = 'C' where Order_ID = new.Order_ID;
  END IF;
END;
```

What this doesn't address is the fact that individual rows in `Sales_Order` can be updated multiple times because of the `FOR EACH ROW` clause (e.g., if two rows with the same Order_ID are updated at the same time, the matching record in `Sales_Order` will be updated twice if the total balance is zero). You can write a more complicated query with a cursor looping over the updated records in order to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for that, being new to triggers could you please guide me to a proper website (if you know any) so that i can read up on it.